# I'm recieving Error: <identifier expected> and Error: illegal start of type for JComboBoxes from addItem statements

Tags: java, eclipse, events, combobox

I have a project for my Java class that requires me to add to JComboBoxes and set events for when they are clicked on to change a pizza price as needed.  Also I know there is something not correct with the event code.  It needs to handle both combo boxes and something isn't correct.  I'm having a tough time understanding what I need to change. Here is the code:

```
// File name JPizza.java
// Written by Me
// Written on 4-26-2014

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class JPizza extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    final int EXTRALARGE_PRICE = 14;
    final int LARGE_PRICE = 11;
    final int MEDIUM_PRICE = 9;
    final int SMALL_PRICE = 7;

    final int CHEESE_PRICE = 0;
    final int PEPPERONI_PRICE = 1;
    final int SAUSAGE_PRICE = 1;
    final int REDONION_PRICE = 1;
    final int GREENPEPPER_PRICE = 1;
    final int MUSHROOM_PRICE = 1;

    int totalPrice = EXTRALARGE_PRICE + CHEESE_PRICE;

    JLabel applicationLabel = new JLabel("Pizza Price Calculator");

    JLabel optionExplainLabel = new JLabel("Select what size, and what topping you want from the drop down menus. Prices are listed in the combo boxes.");

    JLabel pizzaSize = new JLabel("Pizza size");
    JComboBox pizzaSizeValue = new JComboBox();
        pizzaSizeValue.addItem("Extra Large - $14");
        pizzaSizeValue.addItem("Large - $11");
        pizzaSizeValue.addItem("Medium - $9");
        pizzaSizeValue.addItem("Small - $7");
        pizzaSizeValue.setSelectedItem("Extra Large - $14");

    JLabel pizzaTopping = new JLabel ("Pizza topping");
    JComboBox pizzaToppingValue = new JComboBox();
        pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Cheese - free");
        pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Pepperoni - $1");
        pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Sausage - $1");
        pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Red Onion - $1");
        pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Green Pepper - $1");
        pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Mushroom - $1");
        pizzaToppingValue.setSelectedItem("Cheese - free");

    JLabel priceLabel = new JLabel("The price for your pizza is");
    JTextField totPrice = new JTextField(3);


    public JPizza()
    {
        super("Pizza Price Calculator");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(applicationLabel);
        add(optionExplainLabel);
        add(pizzaSize);
        add(pizzaSizeValue);
        add(pizzaTopping);
        add(pizzaToppingValue);
        add(priceLabel);
        add(totPrice);
        totPrice.setText("$" + totalPrice);
        pizzaSizeValue.addActionListener(this);
        pizzaToppingValue.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        int pizzaSizeCost = 14;
        int pizzaToppingCost = 0;
        JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) event.getSource();
        Object source = event.getSource();
        Object select = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
        if(source == pizzaSizeValue)
        {
            if(select.equals("Extra Large - $14"))
                pizzaSizeCost = EXTRALARGE_PRICE;
            if(select.equals("Large - $11"))
                pizzaSizeCost = LARGE_PRICE;
            if(select.equals("Medium - $9"))
                pizzaSizeCost = MEDIUM_PRICE;
            if(select.equals("Small - $7"))
                pizzaSizeCost = SMALL_PRICE;
        }
        if(source == pizzaToppingValue)
        {
            if(select.equals("Cheese - free"))
                pizzaSizeCost = CHEESE_PRICE;
            if(select.equals("Pepperoni $1"))
                pizzaSizeCost = PEPPERONI_PRICE;
            if(select.equals("Sausage $1"))
                pizzaSizeCost = SAUSAGE_PRICE;
            if(select.equals("Red Onion $1"))
                pizzaSizeCost = REDONION_PRICE;
            if(select.equals("Green Pepper $1"))
                pizzaSizeCost = GREENPEPPER_PRICE;
            if(select.equals("Mushroom $1"))
                pizzaSizeCost = MUSHROOM_PRICE;
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JPizza aFrame =
            new JPizza();
            final int WIDTH = 300;
            final int HEIGHT = 200;
            aFrame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            aFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here are the errors:

```
c:\Java\Homework\CH14\YouDoIt>javac JPizza.java
JPizza.java:31: error: <identifier> expected
                pizzaSizeValue.addItem("Extra Large - $14");
                                      ^
JPizza.java:31: error: illegal start of type
                pizzaSizeValue.addItem("Extra Large - $14");
                                       ^
JPizza.java:32: error: <identifier> expected
                pizzaSizeValue.addItem("Large - $11");
                                      ^
JPizza.java:32: error: illegal start of type
                pizzaSizeValue.addItem("Large - $11");
                                       ^
JPizza.java:33: error: <identifier> expected
                pizzaSizeValue.addItem("Medium - $9");
                                      ^
JPizza.java:33: error: illegal start of type
                pizzaSizeValue.addItem("Medium - $9");
                                       ^
JPizza.java:34: error: <identifier> expected
                pizzaSizeValue.addItem("Small - $7");
                                      ^
JPizza.java:34: error: illegal start of type
                pizzaSizeValue.addItem("Small - $7");
                                       ^
JPizza.java:35: error: <identifier> expected
                pizzaSizeValue.setSelectedItem("Extra Large - $14");
                                              ^
JPizza.java:35: error: illegal start of type
                pizzaSizeValue.setSelectedItem("Extra Large - $14");
                                               ^
JPizza.java:39: error: <identifier> expected
                pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Cheese - free");
                                         ^
JPizza.java:39: error: illegal start of type
                pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Cheese - free");
                                          ^
JPizza.java:40: error: <identifier> expected
                pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Pepperoni - $1");
                                         ^
JPizza.java:40: error: illegal start of type
                pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Pepperoni - $1");
                                          ^
JPizza.java:41: error: <identifier> expected
                pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Sausage - $1");
                                         ^
JPizza.java:41: error: illegal start of type
                pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Sausage - $1");
                                          ^
JPizza.java:42: error: <identifier> expected
                pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Red Onion - $1");
                                         ^
JPizza.java:42: error: illegal start of type
                pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Red Onion - $1");
                                          ^
JPizza.java:43: error: <identifier> expected
                pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Green Pepper - $1");
                                         ^
JPizza.java:43: error: illegal start of type
                pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Green Pepper - $1");
                                          ^
JPizza.java:44: error: <identifier> expected
                pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Mushroom - $1");
                                         ^
JPizza.java:44: error: illegal start of type
                pizzaToppingValue.addItem("Mushroom - $1");
                                          ^
JPizza.java:45: error: <identifier> expected
                pizzaToppingValue.setSelectedItem("Cheese - free");
                                                 ^
JPizza.java:45: error: illegal start of type
                pizzaToppingValue.setSelectedItem("Cheese - free");
                                                  ^
24 errors

Any help would be appreciated!
```

Answer (score 0):

The offending code is found naked out in the class, outside of any constructor or a method, and it cannot exist there. Only variable or type declarations and initializations can exist there. Your offending code should probably be located in your class's constructor.

Note that this problem has really little to do with JComboBoxes or even Swing and all to do with a general Java issue of your trying to make method calls on variables outside of a method or constructor. You can declare and initialize variables out in the class, but you can't make method calls there.

Comment: Is that only true with JComboBoxes? I'm guessing adding items to the combo box isn't an initialization.

Comment: Moving it from the class declaration to the class constructor fixed the problem, thank you.

Comment: @dk_sn1p3r: the problem has nothing to do with JComboBoxes per se, and all to do with your trying to make method calls on variables outside of a method or constructor. You can declare and initialize variables out in the class, but you can't make method calls there.